# Join 3 tables in .net core entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, linq-to-sql

I need to get all room list with reservation details and guest details if there is any reservation with perticular room. join 3 tables using LINQ with ef. Here how I did.

```
var _list = (

                        from G in _DbEntity.ReservationGuestDetail
                        join R in _DbEntity.Room
                        on G.RoomNumber equals R.RoomNumber
                        join RE in _DbEntity.Reservation on G.ReservationNumber equals RE.ReservationNumber into RR
                        from Res in RR.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        where
                        G.Pmscustcode == PMSCustCode &&
                        R.PmsCustCode == PMSCustCode &&
                        R.IsDeleted == false &&
                        G.IsDeleted == false &&
                        Res.IsDeleted == false &&
                        Res.Pmscustcode == PMSCustCode

                        select new
                        {
                            RoomId = R.RoomId,
                            RoomNumber = R.RoomNumber,
                            RoomType = R.RoomTypeName,
                            ReservationDateFrom = G.ArrivalDateTime,
                            ReservationDateTo = G.DepartureDateTime,
                            ReservationNumber = Res.ReservationNumber,
                            ReservationStatus = Res.ReservationStatus,
                            GuestName = G.GuestFirstName + " " + G.GuestLastName
                        }
                            ).OrderBy(x => x.RoomId).ToList();
```

UPDATE :
With this code, its return the reservation made rooms only. But I need to get all of the rooms if there are any reservation made or not.

Response :

```
[
        {
            "roomId": 1,
            "roomNumber": "K100",
            "roomType": "Standard King",
            "guestName": "Test user",
            "reservationStatus": "Expected",
            "reservationNumber": "20",
            "reservationDateFrom": "2020-03-31",
            "reservationDateTo": "2020-04-02"
        },
        {
            "roomId": 2,
            "roomNumber": "K101",
            "roomType": "Standard King",
            "guestName": "",
            "reservationStatus": "",
            "reservationNumber": "",
            "reservationDateFrom": "",
            "reservationDateTo": ""
        },
        {
            "roomId": 3,
            "roomNumber": "K102",
            "roomType": "Standard King",
            "guestName": "",
            "reservationStatus": "",
            "reservationNumber": "",
            "reservationDateFrom": "",
            "reservationDateTo": ""
        }]
```

Comment: And what is your question? Does the code you posted work?

Comment: @DavidG This code is working. but the thing is it's not returning all of the rooms. only the reservation made room returned. Let me update the question

Comment: First, use navigation properties, not joins. Then EF will automatically use outer joins where necessary and the code becomes a lot easier.

Comment: @GertArnold can you show me how to do it. I'm new to ef and .netcore

Comment: Do what? Anyway, EF core has excellent documentation.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks I will try

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi I need to get a response as above to refer the response

Comment: I guess you should use left join Room Table  with Reservation Table ,and left join with Reservation Table and Guest Table .This solution give you all rooms with other details.even if nobody don't reservation this room. Is it right?

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi yes. That's right. But how to do it in ef

Comment: If you put all your classes maybe I can do it

Comment: If you need all rooms you should start the query at `_DbEntity.Room` and left join from there, using navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold This is DB first approach. Is navigation property valid for that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below linq code:

```
var _list = (
                from R in _DbEntity.Room
                join G in _DbEntity.ReservationGuestDetail on R.RoomNumber equals G.RoomNumber into RG
                from x in RG.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join RE in _DbEntity.Reservation on x.ReservationNumber equals RE.ReservationNumber into GRE
                from y in GRE.DefaultIfEmpty()

                select new
                {
                    RoomId = R.RoomId,
                    RoomNumber = R.RoomNumber,
                    RoomType = R.RoomTypeName,
                    ReservationDateFrom = x.ArrivalDateTime,
                    ReservationDateTo = x.DepartureDateTime,
                    ReservationNumber = y.ReservationNumber,
                    ReservationStatus = y.ReservationStatus,
                    GuestName = x.GuestFirstName + " " + x.GuestLastName

                }).OrderBy(x => x.RoomId).ToList();
```

Comment: This only returns the rooms which only reserved. But I need all the rooms if there are reservation or not